# React Native - Redux Form focus is not a function

Tags: react-native, redux-form, native-base

Here is my code:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log(this.refs.lastName.getRenderedComponent());
    this.refs.lastName.getRenderedComponent().focus();

}

render() {
    return (
        <Grid containerStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>

            <Row size={3.5} containerStyle={styles.topContainer}>
                <View>
                    <Field type="text" returnKeyType={"next"} ref="firstName" withRef
                           name="firstName" label="First Name" component={RenderField}/>

                    <Field last type="text" name="lastName" label="Last Name"
                           ref="lastName" withRef component={RenderField}/>

                </View>
            </Row>

        </Grid>
    )
}

 // Render Field

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import {Item, Input, Label} from 'native-base';

class RenderField extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {input, label, type, meta: {touched, error, invalid, warning}, custom} = this.props;

        let hasError = false;
        if (error !== undefined) {
            hasError = true;
        }
        return (
            <Item floatingLabel error={hasError} style={{marginBottom: 20}}>
                <Label>{label}</Label>
                <Input {...input} {...custom}/>
                {hasError ? <Text>{error}</Text> : <Text />}
            </Item>
        )
    }
}

export default RenderField;
```

The console.log return properly but at `this.refs.lastName.getRenderedComponent().focus();` it always return this error `_this.refs.lastName.getRenderedComponent().focus is not a function`.

How can I set focus on specific input text?

I'm using Redux Form v6 and Native Base v2

Thanks.

Comment: _this.refs.lastName.getRenderedComponent().focus will work inside componentDidUpdate(). Just try it

Comment: @Codesingh its not returning any error, but the text input wont get focus. And if you start typing at the input it will return same error like above.

Comment: redux-form version?

Comment: @Codesingh v6.6.3

Comment: use like this : ref={(input) => { this.lastName= input; }}

Comment: @Codesingh already tried it shows different error. `Cannot read property 'getRenderedComponent' of undefined`

Comment: where did you try that? in componentDidMount?

Comment: @Codesingh yes. `componentDidUpdate` will return same error when start typing.

Comment: is your component stateless ?

Comment: @Codesingh nope. My above code show it.

Comment: @StefenSuhat The issue you are facing, is added onto our GitHub Issues list. Check [here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/874) for updates